# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 0x32 (Array accessed at an out-of-bounds or negative index)

Tags: hardhat, solidity-0.8.x

In the process of updating sushiswap contracts to solidity 8 I run into this issue while running this [test](https://gist.github.com/pynchmeister/7fb990cdd5f061cc0c425048226fc0c0) accompanied by this [contract](https://gist.github.com/pynchmeister/5c00ed3de6415e3619715564d2d642d1). Here is the error in full:

```
       Set
         Should revert if invalid pool:

      AssertionError: expected 'Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 0x32 (Array accessed at an out-of-bounds or negative index)' to equal 'Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode'
      + expected - actual

      -Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 0x32 (Array accessed at an out-of-bounds or negative index)
      +Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
      
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/MiniZapDirectorV2.test.ts:56:14)
      at step (test/MiniZapDirectorV2.test.ts:33:23)
      at Object.throw (test/MiniZapDirectorV2.test.ts:14:53)
      at rejected (test/MiniZapDirectorV2.test.ts:6:65)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error when i was using improper sytax for pushing elements in a dynamic array. i know it's silly but might be helpful for someone.

What i was doing, which caused the error:

```
waves[count] = msg.sender;
```

What fixed it:

```
waves.push(msg.sender);
```